# How to use CORS in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cors

How do I use CORS for data retrieval from a HTTPS URL to localhost in JavaScript? The URL is a Service-Now incident list that I need to process as a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

CORS is a server side feature that the new browsers support.

When you request a resource from a cross domain service, the browser performs a preflight request to the server and asks him for access information.

If the server allows you to access it's resource from a different domain, it will send back some HTTP headers and the browser will decide upon those headers about your actions.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it, provided server side configurations are done:

```
// Create the XHR object.
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

// Helper method to parse the title tag from the response.
function getTitle(text) {
  return text.match('<title>(.*)?</title>')[1];
}

// Make the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest() {
  // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.
  var url = 'http://updates.html5rocks.com';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    var title = getTitle(text);
    alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
  };

  xhr.send();
}
```

This is from: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'url'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:xyz' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

This is the error i'm getting while executing the above code.